# Apache randomly loses permission to see files

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, configuration, phusion-passenger

I have a server (Leopard Server, not my choice) running Apache and MySQL. Several months ago, the server began to raise "Forbidden" errors at random intervals, preventing access to a PHP application. This behavior randomly ceased.

Now, several days ago I installed Passenger and deployed a Sintra/Rack application. The application runs as a user `acarneg` (for example) from `/Library/WebServer/Documents/presto/current/public`, `acarneg` owns the entire structure. The `_www` user has access to the directory via ACL `chmod +a "_www allow read,write,..."`.

Everything works great! **But** after a randomish interval, often ~12 or ~24 hours, Passenger throws an error that also prevents the PHP application from running. `Passenger Error #2. Cannot stat file config.ru. Permission denied.` But the permissions haven't changed (confirmed) and all one has to do to resolve the error is `sudo apachectl graceful`.

If the permissions aren't changing and Apache doesn't seem to have a legit problem, what is causing this mess? Why did it stop before, and why has it resumed!?!?!?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Apache is probably reaching the maximum open files limit. Apache will cause permission errors and it also explains why it takes a while and is resolved by reloading Apache.

I'm not really familiarly with Mac's but there should be a command to check the open files of a process. (eg. lsof, pfiles, procfiles).

Possible resolutions are:

- Increase the maximum open files (ulimit)
- Reduce the number of log files
- Check if the PHP code closes all it's files

See also [File Descriptor Limit](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/fd-limits.html) in the Apache documentation.

Comment: The PHP scripts should close any open files when it finishes. Using sessions (especially with a large timeout) will prolong this. But you should still try to find a way to monitor the (amount of) open files to make sure this is the problem.

Comment: It actually seems that this is not the problem. PHP's only file handling operation seems to be move_uploaded_files

Answer (score 1):

Where is the filesystem storage?  Does it require kerberos to access the data, or AFS or something else, so that your problem is an expiring ticket?

Comment: It's on the system volume, which, in this case is formatted HFS+ Journaled. There should be no interruption in service to the disk.